# Min height of page

Tags: css

I am using the Weaver theme and would like to set the minimum page height to a certain size. I have read about it and added:

```
min-height: 900;
```

to my style sheet but it does not seem to be working. What should I do?

Comment: This question is concerning CSS only, and not WordPress. Please see the [FAQ](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help) for posting here.

Comment: Well since it is the Weaver theme, this would normally work outside of Wordpress and since I am just starting to use Wordpress and get my head around it I thought it maybe a Wordpress question. My apologies sir that I have made such a huge error - and all I wanted was a little help. Silly me.

Comment: Suggestions for you.  1> learn how to use child theme. very easy. 2> Learn how to dynamically change settings using firebug (inside the firefox browser) and/or chrome (developer tools)  You can view your site, make temporary changes to the CSS on the site and immediately see results.  Good way to test. After test, make changes to your child-theme style.css, upload and refresh your browser. Good luck with it.

Comment: @zipzit thanks - got there. I know I need to get my head around child themes (on the list) but firebug did the trick. Thank you - Very helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set `min-height` to **900px** instead of just **900**.

900 might work in some browsers, but probably not in yours.